# MineSweeper game array

Tags: java

I have the same problem as some guy who asked this.

I want to code some basic stuff for a little minesweeper game.
Now I have the problem that my code

```
public class Minesweeper1 {

     public static int[][]  makeRandomBoard(int s, int z, int n){


     int feld[][] = new int [s][z];
     for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < z; j++){
             feld[i][j] = 0;
         } 
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          selectRandomPosition(s, z);
          feld[randomHeight][randomWidth] = 1;
      }
    }
```

so it starts the selectRandomPosition code:

```
public static int[] selectRandomPosition(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    int randomHeight = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxHeight);
    int randomWidth = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxWidth);
    return new int[]{randomHeight, randomWidth};
}
```

Here I am not allowed to change anything, but it returns a new array. Now my question is how can I use the new array in `makeRandomBoard`?, since I do not know any name of the array. When I use `feld[randomHeight][randomWidth] = 1;` it says that it does not know these variables.

And he did get the answer:
Call the method, and assign its return value to a variable. Now you have a name for the array:

```
// Make a call
int[] randomArray = selectRandomPosition(maxW, maxH);
// Access the width
int randomW = randomArray[0];
// Access the height
int randomH = randomArray[1];
```

but what do I have to write now?
I tried it with:

```
feld[randomW][randomH] = 1;
```

but it seems like it doesn't work. I also need a return statement.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's a terrible title. Please use the title to summarize the problem at hand.

Comment: How does this relate to C?

Comment: You have got 2 random numbers, what you need to do with them ?

Comment: `feld[randomH][randomW] = 1;` But note that you've reversed your assignments, it should be `int randomW = randomArray[1];` and `int randomH = randomArray[0];` Finally the last line of `makeRandomBoard` before the closing brace should `return feld;`

Comment: this is a very weird question

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for:

### Solution

```java
public class Minesweeper1 {
    // Note:
    // s == Height
    // z == Width
    public static int[][] makeRandomBoard(int s, int z, int n) {
        // Note: Misspelling of "field"?
        int feld[][] = new int [s][z];

        // Initialize the game board with no mines (value of 0)
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < z; j++) {
                feld[i][j] = 0;
            } 
        }

        // Iterate through n times to place "mines" (value of 1)
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            // selectRandomPosition returns an array of length 2
            // the first index (0) = randomHeight
            // the second index (1) = randomWidth
            // Notice that z and s is flipped
            // because the first parameter is for width, which is z
            // and the second parameter is for height, which is s
            int[] position = selectRandomPosition(z, s);
            int positionX = position[1];
            int positionY = position[0];
            // The order of positionY/positionX is key!
            // If it's in the wrong order you will get an
            // IndexOutOfBoundsException!
            feld[positionY][positionX] = 1;
        }

        // Return the newly created array
        return feld;
    }

    public static int[] selectRandomPosition(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        int randomHeight = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxHeight);
        int randomWidth = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxWidth);
        // Notice that this is returning a fixed array of two elements
        // the first being the Y component, and the second being the X
        // component.
        return new int[]{randomHeight, randomWidth};
    }
}
```

### Problems

#### Passing the wrong values

You were calling `selectRandomPosition` wrong.  Remember that `s` is the Height, and `z` is the Width.  So you were passing into `selectRandomPosition` the Height for the first parameter, and the Width for the second parameter.  Look at the method declaration:

```java
public static int[] selectRandomPosition(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
```

That meant you passed the Height into the `maxWidth`, and the Width into the `maxHeight`.  My solution flips it for you.  This can be confusing because `s` and `z` don't really give you hints to what they are (Height and Width) - consider renaming these variables to help you.

#### Accessing in the wrong order

You have in your question:

```java
feld[randomW][randomH] = 1;
```

This is wrong, it should be:

```java
feld[randomH][randomW] = 1;
```

This image shows a visual representaion of what a two dimensional array looks like:

[image: Two Dimensional Array]

So the access would be:

```java
feld[0][0] == 1
feld[0][1] == 1
feld[0][2] == 1
feld[1][0] == 1
feld[1][1] == 2
feld[1][2] == 4
feld[2][0] == 1
feld[2][1] == 3
feld[2][2] == 9
```

#### Nit-Pick: Misspellings

Other than having weird variable names like `s` and `z` that do not help you at all in remembering what means what, your main variable that you will eventually return is misspelled.  Did you mean "field"?

Variable naming is important and can help you, and other readers, to easily understand your code.  Also, comments in places where you think you need them also help!